# How to revert a package?

Tags: packages

I want to install SC Hotfix 455749-1.zip for Sitecore XP 10.0.1.
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000580 says to install it from CM. So after installing it like a normal package, in case it breaks application, how to revert it.

Answer (score 1):

Safer side you can take backup of Sitecore site files and databases. You can also extract the package and see what files or items it contains. Then you can take backup of those specific items.

I found that package contains following files. So you can check and take backup of these files before installing this package. If anything go wrong then you can revert these files.

Config files:

1. App_Config\Sitecore\Services.Client\Sitecore.Services.Client.config

Bin:

Sitecore.Client.dll

Sitecore.Content.Services.dll

Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.dll

Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.dll

Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.dll

Sitecore.Kernel.dll

Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.dll

Sitecore.Services.Client.dll

Sitecore.Services.Core.dll

Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.dll

Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.dll

Comment: The package showed me only an update file. Where these dlls in the extracted package? Or is it like when i install that hotfix, it will update these dlls

Comment: The .update file is actual just a .zip file, you should be able to open it with a zip tool, or change the extension to .zip to open and to look at the file's inside

Comment: Is it required to intsall this package in sitecore through CM or just overide these dlls in bin

Comment: You need to use installation wizard to install this package. Just check "readme.txt" file in that hotfix package for Installation instructions.